# Insert statement doesn't recognise the variable values

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

The code that's on the package works fine. From the oracle form, I'm trying to insert new entry into the table.

***Error Message***

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("BUS"."BP_AUTH_CODE"."CODE")

***Code***

```
Declare
    v_bn varchar2(9);
    v_bn_exists number;
    v_has_auth_code number;
    v_auth_code varchar2(9);
Begin
    v_bn := :TAC.bn;

    v_bn_exists := CG$BP_AUTH_CODE.bn_exists(v_bn);

    if v_bn_exists = 1 then
        .....

        if v_has_auth_code = 1 then
            ...
        else
            v_auth_code := CG$BP_AUTH_CODE.make_auth_code;
            --Error happening over here
            insert into bp_auth_code (bn, code) values(v_bn, v_auth_code);
            commit;
            message(v_auth_code); -- I can see the value
        end if; 

    else
        ....
    end if;

End;
```

Comment: Do you have a trigger which replicates the same value to the table with the same name, different schema(bus). I mean, are you sure that your forms connects to the `bus` schema in the runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you got this wrong:

```
v_auth_code := CG$BP_AUTH_CODE.make_auth_code;
--Error happening over here
insert into bp_auth_code (bn, code) values(v_bn, v_auth_code);
commit;
message(v_auth_code); -- I can see the value
```

Saying that "you can see the value" - no, you can not.

If `INSERT` failed, Oracle raised the ORA-01400 error so execution stops. Nothing behind `INSERT` is executed, which includes `MESSAGE` call. You can't possibly know the value, but - if I were you, I'd trust Oracle on that one. If it says that `CODE` is null, then it is.

Depending on Forms version you use, you can (always) rewrite code (for debugging purposes) as

```
v_auth_code := CG$BP_AUTH_CODE.make_auth_code;
message(v_auth_code);             -- now you'll see the V_AUTH_CODE value
insert into bp_auth_code (bn, code) values(v_bn, v_auth_code);
commit;
```

or run the form in debug mode (don't forget to set the breakpoint!) and trace its execution.